# How to make bibliography(bibtex) and enumerate indentation the same?

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way in the following MWE to have the indentation in the bibliography to be the same as that in enumerate?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}


\makeatletter \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.} \makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.

\item Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae.


\end{enumerate}

\nocite{tstItem1,tstItem2}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{tst}

\end{document}
```

tst.bib

```
@Misc{tstItem1,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem2,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
```

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wished you explained why you want the indentation in the bibliography to be the same as that in enumerate.

At last I see the problem there that the indentation is variable and depends on the number of bib entrys you have in your documents.

I only have a quick and dirty solution. Please see the  following four lines:

```
% \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{~~~~#1.} %  1-9  bib entrys, file \jobname
  \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{~~~#1.}  % 10-99 bib entrys, file \jobname-2
```

and

```
%\bibliography{\jobname}   % <================== bib file with  2 entrys
 \bibliography{\jobname-2} % <================== bib file with 10 entrys
```

I added---depending on the number of bib entrys in your bib file---some `~` (fixed space) in your changed command `\@biblabel` to get the effect you want.

Depending on the number of bib entrys you have to use different commands.  So I showed the effect for 10 bib entrys (second file created by `filecontents`). If you want to see the effect for two bib entrys please move in both parts of two lines the leading `%` to the second line ...

With the complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{tstItem1,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem2,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@Misc{tstItem1,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem2,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
@Misc{tstItem3,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem4,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
@Misc{tstItem5,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem6,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
@Misc{tstItem7,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem8,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
@Misc{tstItem9,
  Title                    = {Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.}
}
@Misc{tstItem10,
  Title                    = {Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter 
% \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{~~~~#1.} %  1-9  bib entrys, file \jobname
  \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{~~~#1.}  % 10-99 bib entrys, file \jobname-2
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Aenean massa. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
    eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, 
    feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. 
    Quisque rutrum.
  \item Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, 
    aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
    imperdiet a, venenatis vitae.
\end{enumerate}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{\jobname}   % <================== bib file with  2 entrys
 \bibliography{\jobname-2} % <================== bib file with 10 entrys

\end{document}
```

you will get the quick-and-dirty result:

[image: ten bib entrys]

To be complete here the result for two bib entrys:

[image: two bib entrys]